# Combine id's into class

Tags: css

For a project I need 4 corner images on certain images. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/put-images-in-all-four-corners-with-css-positioning/) is a good example. My problem is not being able to use Sass. I have to do it in CSS only.

How can I combine id's into a class? Is that possible?

---

I have read the example. If I have to do it that way, I have to add for each and every image a lengthy list with id's. If I can combine the id's into CSS I only have to make one statement.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to follow the appropriate guidelines.

Comment: IN your own link there is example with pure CSS. https://css-tricks.com/examples/AllFourCorners/ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```css
.corners {
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url('https://css-tricks.com/examples/AllFourCorners/images/upper-left.jpg'), url('https://css-tricks.com/examples/AllFourCorners/images/upper-right.jpg'), url('https://css-tricks.com/examples/AllFourCorners/images/lower-left.jpg'), url('https://css-tricks.com/examples/AllFourCorners/images/lower-right.jpg');
  background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="corners">
  Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br> Some text here<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.